# bash sort on multiple fields and deduplicating

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to sort data like the below content on the first field first and then on the date in the third field. Then keep only the latest for each ID(field 1) - irrespective of the second field.

```
id1,description1,2013/11/20
id2,description2,2013/06/11
id2,description3,2012/10/28
id2,description4,2011/12/04
id3,description5,2014/02/09
id3,description6,2013/12/05
id4,description7,2013/12/05
id5,description8,2013/08/14
```

So the expected output will be

```
id1,description1,2013/11/20
id2,description2,2013/06/11
id3,description5,2014/02/09
id4,description7,2013/12/05
id5,description8,2013/08/14
```

Thanks
Jomon

Comment: Use `sort` to sort it, and `awk` to de-duplicate the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
> cat file
id1,description1,2013/11/20
id1,description1,2013/11/19
id2,description2,2013/06/11
id2,description3,2012/10/28
id2,description4,2011/12/04
id3,description5,2014/02/09
id3,description6,2013/12/05
id4,description7,2013/12/05
id5,description8,2013/08/14

> sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3r file | awk -F, '!a[$1]++'
id1,description1,2013/11/20
id2,description2,2013/06/11
id3,description5,2014/02/09
id4,description7,2013/12/05
id5,description8,2013/08/14
```

Comment: I didn't say this about the other answer to you I feel I must: the way you've done it _happens_ to produce the correct answer for the given input.  As an example, add `id1,description1,2013/11/19` to line 2 of the input and observe what you'd get.

Comment: If I insert `id1,description1,2013/11/19` at record # 2 then in the output it shows `id1,description1,2013/11/19` as the first record.

Comment: Exactly, that's what makes it incorrect.  The desired output should contain latest date, i.e. it should be `2013/11/20` and not `2013/11/19`.  (Assuming I got the question correct.)

Comment: After reading question again I think you are right. I thought earliest date record was needed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to nitpick.  Pointed because it came from _you_.

Comment: Oh no problem at all, its indeed a valid point. I regard your opinions very high.

Comment: Only because of your comment I edited my answer. Please check, hope it is fine now.

Comment: Nice use of awk arrays, I've learned something very useful today!

Comment: And I kept on the redundant `print` in there!

Comment: It worked great! I had a data file with 6000+ lines... and from the random 10-20 output lines I checked, all are OK. Thanks very much!

Comment: It's ok.  I deleted my answer because it appeared to seem redundant after a while.

Answer (score 1):

Call `sort` twice; the first time, sort by the date. On the second call, sort uniquely on the first field, but do so stably so that items with the same id remain sorted by date.

```
sort -t, -k3,3r data.txt | sort -t, -su -k1,1
```

Comment: Probably never occurred that one could use `-u` in conjunction with `-k`.  Fantastic!

Comment: In an ideal world, `sort -t, -k3,3r -k1,1u data.txt` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat file |sort -u|awk -F, '{if(map[$1] == ""){print $0; map[$1]="printed"}}'
```

**Explanation**:

I use `sort` to sort (well could not be more simple)

And I use awk to store in a map if the first column item was already printed.

If not (map[$1] == "") I print and store "printed" into map[$1] (so next time it won't be equal to "" for the current value of $1).